# Why they are using linq Expression here @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id) @department.Name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to know why they are using linq Expression in this 
statement:

`@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id) @department.Name.How` the value of property (Selected Department of company class)
  is set when get event of Index controller is called and how the value of 
SelectedDepartment (property of company class) is retrieved.

```
Code:   

        //This a model class

        public class Company
        {
            public string SelectedDepartment { get; set; } //Property
            public List<Department> Departments //Property
            {
                get
                {
                    SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();
                    return db.Departments.ToList();
                }
            }
        } 

        // This is a controller class

        class HomeController
        {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index() //Controller Method1
        {
            Company company = new Company();
            return View(company);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Index(Company company) //Controller Method2
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(company.SelectedDepartment))
            {
                return "You did not select any department";
            }
            else
            {
                return "You selected department with ID = " + company.SelectedDepartment;
            }
        }
        }

       // This is a view

        @model MVCDemo.Models.Company
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }

        <h2>Index</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            foreach (var department in Model.Departments)
            {
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id) @department.Name
            }
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        }
```

Comment: Bit unclear exactly what your asking. Your generating a radio button group that has the name `SelectedDepartment ` - the html looks like `<input type="radio"  name="SelectedDepartment " .... />`. When you submit, the form posts back a name/pair value in the form data (`SelectedDepartment: theValueYouSelected`) which matches a property in your model so its value is set by the `DefaultModelBinder`

Comment: stephen by  words in this statement (m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id) @department.Name...m => m.SelectedDepartment : is this statement name of radio button

Comment: `m => m.SelectedDepartment` is an expression describing your property. The html helper uses the name of the property (in this case "SelectedDepartment") to generate the `name` attribute. Because your generating multiple radio button (in the `foreach` loop) all with the same name, they form a radio button group (meaning only one can be selected from that group. Since each one has a different value (the value of `department.Id`, when you post, the value of the selected button along with the name are sent to the controller

Comment: stephen but how does the property SelectedDepartment gets set...

Comment: Get set where? Do you mean in the POST method?

Comment: in both get and post request.. but how does the property SelectedDepartment gets set.

Comment: Not really sure what your wanting to know. You set the value in the GET method - e.g `company.SelectedDepartment = someValue;` The `DefaultModelBinder` (which is called when you hit the POST method) first initializes your model (because its a parameter of the method), then reads the form values (which will include `SelectedDepartment: theValueOfYourSelectedRadioButton` and because you model includes a property named `SelectedDepartment` its value will be set.

Comment: Even the name of the Radio button is set same as the property name ...how  does the name of property and radio button can be same

Comment: You need to do some research on what a html radio button is. When you have a group of radio buttons where you want to be able to select one from the group, they MUST have the same name (otherwise you could select more than one, or all of them, and you could never unselect any of them)

Comment: i know that but the name of the radio button and property of company class are same i.e SelectedDepartment from the below statement...@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id) @department.Name

Comment: Because that's what html helpers do. They generate form controls with `name` attributes matching the name of the property they are binding to so that they can be matched up with you model when your post. How else do you think you could bind to your properties.

Comment: Stephen Muecke ...i'm new to mvc...can u explain how binding takes place so that property and radio button has same name

Comment: Far to long to explain the detail. I suggest you look at the MVC source code - [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs) for the `RadioButtonFor()` method which generates the html, and [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) for the `DefaultModelBinder` which binds the form values back to your model

Comment: Stephen Muecke can u suggest me some sites,books or any other good sources to learn mvc.i want to understand mvc from basic to depth